# merge two dict in python having the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i have the following two dicts as

```
dict1 = {'roll':{1:{'abc':100},2:{'abc':200},4:{'abc':900}},'no_roll':{}}

dict2 = {'roll':{1:{'cde':500},2:{'cde':600}},'no_roll':{4:{'cde':500}}}
```

and i would like to merge get a dict like,

```
final_dict = {'roll': {1: {'abc': 100,'cde': 500},2:{'abc': 200,'cde': 600},4:{'abc':900}},'no_roll': {4:{'cde':500}}}
```

I was able to do with multiple for loop and if conditions.How can I do that with a line or two of code?

Comment: will the dictionary always be a consistent depth?

Comment: Why would you want to compromise on code readability by doing it in a line or two?

Comment: @Recessive It will not be consistent. values of roll and no_roll will vary depends on scenarios but the keys will be present either in roll or no_roll

Comment: this will [help](https://gist.github.com/angstwad/bf22d1822c38a92ec0a9)

Comment: @Gopi check my answer below and see if it helps you

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh. Thanks for your answer. It works. I have another case where dict1 or dict2 keys need not be in `roll` key it can be under `no_roll` also. I need to merge the dict appropriately based on the parent key. For example , keys 1 and 2 can either be under `roll` or `no_roll`. same in dict2. Updated the question.

Comment: My output will be `{'roll': {1: {'cde': 500, 'abc': 900}, 2: {'cde': 600, 'abc': 900}}, 'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500, 'abc': 900}}}`, will that work?

Comment: It doesnt give correct output for my case. It should be like this `{'roll': {1: {'abc': 100,'cde': 500},2:{'abc': 200,'cde': 600},4:{'abc':900}},'no_roll': {4:{'cde':500}}}` . In `'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500, 'abc': 900}}`. `'abc':900` should not come under `no_roll`. It should come under `roll`

Comment: Okay I will update my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generic method

To merge two dicts with nested dicts, you have to perform a tree traversal (e. g. DFS):

```
>>> d1 = {'roll':{1:{'abc':100},2:{'abc':200},4:{'abc':900}},'no_roll':{}}
>>> d2 = {'roll':{1:{'cde':500},2:{'cde':600}},'no_roll':{4:{'cde':500}}}

>>> def merge(d1, d2):
...     d = {k: d1[k] for k in set(d1) - set(d2)}
...     d.update({k: d2[k] for k in set(d2) - set(d1)})
...     for k in set(d2) & set(d1):
...         assert isinstance(d1[k], dict) == isinstance(d2[k], dict), "inconsistent dicts"
...         if isinstance(d1[k], dict):
...              d[k] = merge(d1[k], d2[k])
...         else:
...             d[k] = d2[k] # keep only the second value, but we can keep a list if needed
...     return d
...
>>> merge(d1, d2)
{'roll': {4: {'abc': 900}, 1: {'abc': 100, 'cde': 500}, 2: {'abc': 200, 'cde': 600}}, 'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500}}}
>>> merge(d1, {'roll':400})
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AssertionError: inconsistent dicts
```

## In your case

**If the keys of the terminal values (`'abc'` and `'cde'`) are never the same in `dict1` and `dict2`**, you can drop some security checks and let the first two lines merge the innermost dicts:

```
>>> def merge2(d1, d2):
...     d = {k: d1[k] for k in set(d1) - set(d2)}
...     d.update({k: d2[k] for k in set(d2) - set(d1)})
...     for k in set(d2) & set(d1):
...         d[k] = merge(d1[k], d2[k])
...     return d
...
>>> merge2(d1, d2)
{'roll': {4: {'abc': 900}, 1: {'abc': 100, 'cde': 500}, 2: {'abc': 200, 'cde': 600}}, 'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500}}}
```

If you want to perform this in two lines:

```
>>> merge3 = lambda d1, d2: {**{k: d1[k] for k in set(d1) - set(d2)}, **{k: d2[k] for k in set(d2) - set(d1)}, **{k: merge3(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in set(d2) & set(d1)}}
>>> merge3(d1, d2)
{'roll': {4: {'abc': 900}, 1: {'abc': 100, 'cde': 500}, 2: {'abc': 200, 'cde': 600}}, 'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500}}}
```

And with Python 3.8, one line:

```
>>> (merge4 := lambda d1, d2: {**{k: d1[k] for k in set(d1) - set(d2)}, **{k: d2[k] for k in set(d2) - set(d1)}, **{k: merge4(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in set(d2) & set(d1)}})(d1, d2)
{'roll': {4: {'abc': 900}, 1: {'abc': 100, 'cde': 500}, 2: {'abc': 200, 'cde': 600}}, 'no_roll': {4: {'cde': 500}}}
```

That was just for fun: do not use clever solutions when they are *too clever*.

Answer (score 2):

A bad one-liner, derived from multiple for loop logic using side-effect will be.

```
{v4.update(v3) for v1 in dict1.values() for v2 in dict2.values() for v3 in v1.values() for v4 in v2.values()}
```

The output will be.

```
print(dict2)
#{'roll': {1: {'cde': 500, 'abc': 200}, 2: {'cbd': 600, 'abc': 200}}, 
#'no_roll': {}}
```

As you can see, the code isn't very readable but does the job

Comment: First two for loops for going till the last depth, and the last two loops to iterate through those dictionaries and appending them

Comment: i won't recomment doing this way, not so pythonic and didn't server the purpose of  dict comprehension

Comment: Yes, as I already mentioned in my answer, it is a `bad one-liner` and using `side-effect`, which is running the loops without assigning the value to a variable!